# DialogFragment force closes

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have used dialog fragment to display a dialog in my app.But when ever i am clicking on the button which displays the dialog the app force closes.

Code

```
public class ShareDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View view;
    private Bundle bundle, bundle1;
    private Button btsharecancel;
    private Button btnonpocketusers;
    private Button btpocketusers;
    private int position;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        initialize();


    }

    private void initialize() {

        btsharecancel = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bt_share_cancel);
        btnonpocketusers = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bt_non_pocket_users);
        btpocketusers = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.bt_pocket_users);
        btnonpocketusers.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        bundle.putInt("position", position);
        Log.e("Position Value", "" + position);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.bt_non_pocket_users:
                ShareDocsEmailFragment shareDocsEmailFragment = new ShareDocsEmailFragment();
                shareDocsEmailFragment.setArguments(bundle1);
                fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frag_container, shareDocsEmailFragment, "shareDocsEmail");
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("shareDocsEmailBack").commit();
                break;


        }

    }
}
```

Before the dialog was being displayed when this code was present

```
public class ShareDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private View view;
    private Bundle bundle, bundle1;
    private Button btsharecancel;
    private Button btnonpocketusers;
    private Button btpocketusers;
    private int position;
    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);


    }


}
```

But when i added the listeners on the button(in dialog) the app closes

LOGCAT

```
07-31 15:54:57.819  12273-12273/example.com.pocketdocs E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at example.com.pocketdocs.ShareDialog.ShareDialogFragment.initialize(ShareDialogFragment.java:57)
            at example.com.pocketdocs.ShareDialog.ShareDialogFragment.onActivityCreated(ShareDialogFragment.java:47)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:852)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1405)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:430)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

i solved the answer with little hassel.The only thing to remember with dialog fragments is to use this

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_dialog, container, false);
        return view;
    } 


         button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
```

INSTEAD OF

```
         button = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button);
```